# What Default Fonts Are Included With iText?

Tags: itext

The iText documentation states that it only includes a certain subset of fonts but never says what those are. Does anyone have any ideas what fonts are included by default in iText?

(I've searched online and haven't been able to find this list of fonts anywhere!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably referring to the [PDF Standard 14 Fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF#Standard_Type_1_Fonts_.28Standard_14_Fonts.29).

Comment: default font is 12 pt

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can find it out in the source code:

```
static BaseFont() {
        BuiltinFonts14.Add(COURIER, PdfName.COURIER);
        BuiltinFonts14.Add(COURIER_BOLD, PdfName.COURIER_BOLD);
        BuiltinFonts14.Add(COURIER_BOLDOBLIQUE, PdfName.COURIER_BOLDOBLIQUE);
        BuiltinFonts14.Add(COURIER_OBLIQUE, PdfName.COURIER_OBLIQUE);
        BuiltinFonts14.Add(HELVETICA, PdfName.HELVETICA);
        BuiltinFonts14.Add(HELVETICA_BOLD, PdfName.HELVETICA_BOLD);
        BuiltinFonts14.Add(HELVETICA_BOLDOBLIQUE, PdfName.HELVETICA_BOLDOBLIQUE);
        BuiltinFonts14.Add(HELVETICA_OBLIQUE, PdfName.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE);
        BuiltinFonts14.Add(SYMBOL, PdfName.SYMBOL);
        BuiltinFonts14.Add(TIMES_ROMAN, PdfName.TIMES_ROMAN);
        BuiltinFonts14.Add(TIMES_BOLD, PdfName.TIMES_BOLD);
        BuiltinFonts14.Add(TIMES_BOLDITALIC, PdfName.TIMES_BOLDITALIC);
        BuiltinFonts14.Add(TIMES_ITALIC, PdfName.TIMES_ITALIC);
        BuiltinFonts14.Add(ZAPFDINGBATS, PdfName.ZAPFDINGBATS);
    }
```